# Python3.4 for loop iteration issues

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I've been working on a project where I iterate through a list of data and remove all of the text before certain characters.  (here's an example for reference)

```
>>> myList = ['foo<foo','bar<bar','baz<baz']
>>> for element in myList:
    for char in element:
        if (char == "<"):
            break
        else:
            charIndex = element.index(char)
            elementIndex = myList.index(element)
            print(charIndex, elementIndex)
            myList[elementIndex] = element[charIndex + 1 :]
0 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 7, in <module>
    elementIndex = myList.index(element)
ValueError: 'foo<foo' is not in list
>>> myList
['oo<foo', 'bar<bar', 'baz<baz']
>>>
```

for reasons unknown to me, the element isn't renamed after it has been reassigned.
Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the first character when setting `myList[elementIndex]=`

```
['oo<foo', 'bar<bar', 'baz<baz']

myList[elementIndex] = element[charIndex + 1:] # removes f

element[charIndex + 1:]  is from the `first index + 1` so it becomes `'oo<foo'`
```

If you put a  `print(element[charIndex + 1 :])` in your loop you will see `'oo<foo'` so `'foo<foo'` will not be in your myList anymore and you will get the `ValueError`

You have assigned  `element` to `'foo<foo'` on the first iteration in `for element in myList` so you are comparing to the original element not the updated list element in the second loop.

You need to update the value of element in the second loop:

```
 myList[elementIndex] = element[charIndex + 1 :]
 element = element[charIndex + 1 :]
```

Which outputs:

```
['<foo', '<bar', '<baz']
```

You can also do this in one line with a list comp, this will also work if "<" is not in some of the strings:

```
[s[s.index("<"):] if "<" in s else s for s in myList ]
```